# Upload text file to Google Cloud storage with ASCII encoding with node

Tags: node.js, character-encoding, google-cloud-storage

A legacy 3rd party I'm working with requires that we provide them with text files using ANSI (~ASCII) character encoding.

The content to be saved to the file is large so I'm using streams. If using the `fs` library I can do something like this:

```
const file = fs.createWriteStream(filePath, {encoding: 'ascii'});

data.pipe(file).on('error', handleError).on('finish', handleSuccess);
```

I'm trying to do the equivalent in the GCS node client:

```
const storage = new Storage();
const gcsFile = storage.bucket(bucket).file(fileName, {});

const fileStream = gcsFile.createWriteStream();


data.pipe(fileStream).on('error', handleError).on('finish', handleSuccess);
```

However the `createWriteStream` method has no such option to specify the character encoding.

Is there a way to explicitly stream data using ASCII character encoding to GCS?

Comment: Do you get any errors or anything specific that is not working ?

Comment: My question is on the possibility of saving a file to GCS using ASCII encoding. The GCS client library does not seen to offer an option to specify encoding like `fs` does

Comment: You may have to use to the [REST API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/streaming#rest-apis) to upload using streams else the NodeSDK works perfectly if you just upload it without streams.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can pass `options.metadata` to the `createWriteStream`. Does something like the following work for you?

```js
gcsFile = gcsBucket.file(fileName);

fs.createReadStream('myLocalFile.txt')
    .pipe(myFile.createWriteStream({
        metadata: {
            contentEncoding: 'ascii'
        }
    }))
    .on('error', handleError)
    .on('finish', handleSuccess);
```

See the client ref docs here: https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/global.html#CreateWriteStreamOptions

Comment: I saw that but assumed the content encoding was different to charset/character encoding. TBH I don't really understand the intricacies. From some test though I found that unless you use non ascii characters the file seems to use `us-ascii` charset by default. Only when I add a character like "" does the charset become utf-8. So I think that metadata is redundant

Comment: You're right! The metadata you need to set is contentType, *not* contentEncoding. Can you try setting `contentType: 'text/plain'`? Or whatever type you need, really.